# How do I combine useLocation() with useSelector()?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

```js
import React from "react"
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { useLocation } from "react-router"

const BreadCrumb = () => {

  const location = useLocation()

  const currentPageTitle = useSelector(state => {

    // match current location to get the currrent page title from redux store and return it
  })

  return (

    <h2>Home / { currentPageTitle}</h2>

  )
}

export default BreadCrumb
```

This code works fine in the initial render and I do get the intended result `{ currentPageTitle }` but the UI doesn't seem to re-render and stays the same despite route change. Although, if I console.log( location ) before the return statement, it logs successfully on route change. What is the issue here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that you use `useEffect` hook:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { useLocation } from "react-router"

const BreadCrumb = () => {
  const location = useLocation()
  const [currentLocation, setCurrentLocation] = useState('')

  const currentPageTitle = useSelector(state => {
    console.log(currentLocation);
    // Do something with currentLocation
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    if (location) {
      setCurrentLocation(location.pathname)
    } else {
      setCurrentLocation('')
    }
  }, [location])

  return (

    <h2>Home / { currentPageTitle}</h2>

  )
}

export default BreadCrumb
```